# DML reference DAL is a technical issue? (dependency injection in .net book)

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, n-tier-architecture

in the book dependency injection in .net (a great book thanks mark).
in page 41 MISCELLANEOUS OTHER ISSUES : 
he speaks about one anti pattern, ui that reference DAL and BLL, DAL that defines Domain Objects (entity framework autogenerated objects) he says :

> Most of the Domain Model seems to be implemented in the Data Access library.
>   **Whereas it’s a technical problem that the Domain Model library references the Data
>   Access library**, it’s a conceptual problem that the Data Access library defines such a
>   class as the Product class. A public Product class belongs in the Domain Model.

i do understand that DAL must not define domain objects.but I don't understand why DML reference DAL is a technical problem?
Are we talking about the BLL(business logic layer) when he speaks about Domain Model Library.

Comment: Most of the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612/126014

Comment: thanks Mark, so if i understand :
+There is a dependency : if an object instantiate another object.
+There is no dependency  : if an object expects an abstraction (contructor injection, method injection ...)
+Assembly References (referencing dll, webservices..) are independant from the dependency concept, because to resolve an abstraction and be able to compile the code,  the layer must reference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Domain Model Library (DML) is a Business Logic Layer (BLL). This library should contain domain model entities (which should be persistent ignorant) and domain services.

Why that is a technical problem? Any changes in DAL will require compilation of DML. If you will inverse dependency, then DAL will act as a plugin for you domain. You will be free to change it (persist data in memory, file, or use other db provider) without affecting BLL.

Comment: So by reference, he means direct reference (tightly coupled)?
Because if i am not wrong, in an n-tier architecture, every layer must referrence the layer under.

Comment: @riadh yes, I think he means direct reference (like adding assembly reference). Also there are architectures where direction of dependencies is not from top to bottom, e.g. Onion (or Hexagonal) architecture - it has domain model in the center, which is referenced by persistence and presentation libraries.

Comment: @riadh The correct definition of n-*layer* architecture is that every layer must *communicate* with the layer beneath it. The architecture doesn't say anything about the direction of assembly references.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky so the question is where to put the shared Contracts (abstractions Interfaces or abstract classes) ?
In a separate assembly ? a seperate assembly for each layer?
Which is the best practice?